# Wordpress 500 - Internal server error (edit)

Tags: windows, wordpress

I'm receiving "500 - Internal server error." on the domain of my WordPress site.

Installed WordPress locally through Web Platform Installer in IIS (Win7).

Developed a landing page in Firefox locally, then FTP'd the site to the web server (which also hosts multiple sites from various domains).

Used MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE to create and export the database, which was also uploaded onto the server. Database was tested.

I've read all the posts relating to "Wordpress" and "500 - Internal server error.", none have helped.

I've tried creating the **.htaccess** file with the following contained:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

All file paths in IIS are correct.

Below is the **wp-config.php** file

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
  *
  * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
  * Secret Keys, WordPress Language, and ABSPATH. You can find more information
  * by visiting {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing
  * wp-config.php} Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
  *
  * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
  * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
  * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
  *
  * @package WordPress
  */

 // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
 /** The name of the database for WordPress */
 define('DB_NAME', 'zxcvb');

 /** MySQL database username */
 define('DB_USER', 'zxcvb');

 /** MySQL database password */
 define('DB_PASSWORD', 'zxcvb');

 /** MySQL hostname */
 define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

 /** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
 define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

 /** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
 define('DB_COLLATE', '');


 /**#@+
  * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
  *
  * Change these to different unique phrases!
  * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1     /salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
  * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This      will force all users to have to log in again.
  *
  * @since 2.6.0
  */
 define('AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here');
 define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here');
 define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here');
 define('NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here');
 define('AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here');
 define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here');
 define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here');
 define('NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here');

 /**#@-*/

 /**
  * WordPress Database Table prefix.
  *
  * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
  * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
  */
 $table_prefix  = 'wp_';

 /**
  * WordPress Localized Language, defaults to English.
  *
  * Change this to localize WordPress. A corresponding MO file for the chosen
  * language must be installed to wp-content/languages. For example, install
  * de_DE.mo to wp-content/languages and set WPLANG to 'de_DE' to enable German
  * language support.
  */
 define('WPLANG', '');

 /**
  * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
  *
  * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Please help!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress stores some domain-specific settings in its options table. If you did the installation locally and then exported it to an external hosting provider it is very likely that those settings are still misconfigured in your WordPress DB and setup for a local installation.

Check the `options` table in WordPress (add your prefix as needed). Look through the rows for those options that make references to your local installation (its URL or resources) and update them with the corresponding values appropriate for your hosting.

In particular, I'd suggest you check the rows with the following `option_name`s:

- siteurl
- home

Once those are setup correctly you should be able to access WP's installation and fix others (like image URLs and some other things like that) from its admin interface.